# Permission error when deploying Docker app from CI server to Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker, continuous-integration, circleci

**The problem**

I'm trying to deploy a Dockerized app from my CI server (Circle) to Heroku.

When I run `heroku docker:release --app <app_name>`, CI logs show the following:

```
Error response from daemon: permission denied
 !   Error in heroku-docker:
 !   Command failed: docker cp 93a67016632af5cffacab9817b741c4dc69b41f0f6d324c8bae53fe98f4e621d:/tmp/slug.tgz /tmp
```

However, I can run this command from my local machine just fine. The API key I have provided to Circle is the same as that from my local user. Also, I can run other Heroku commands, such as `heroku logs --app <app_name>`, from the CI server just fine.

Why are there permission errors?

**Extra background info**

It appears the only way Heroku supports Docker is using the Docker Toolbelt, with the Docker plugin (`heroku docker:release --app <app_name>`). At the same time, the recommended way to deploy to Heroku in CircleCI is using a [special entry](https://circleci.com/docs/continuous-deployment-with-heroku) in the proprietary `circle.yml` file. However, this doesn't support Docker, which is why I'm choosing the `heroku docker:release` method.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen dockerd report permission denied when the actual error is disk fault or security service preventing access.

Look at /var/log/messages or other system log while doing the docker command that fails.

e.g. look at /var/log/messages while doing docker cp command.

```
$ docker cp b54433de86ec:/thing ./
Error response from daemon: permission denied
```

E.g. you might see errors related to vmount

```
Nov 17 10:57:45 machine dockerd: time="2021-11-17T10:57:45.063942786Z" level=warning msg="b54433de86ecd8426c27e8c8fa7e6a785fa8e513a5133d3a41b163308f0d59a5 unmountVolumes: Failed to do lazy umount fo volume '/logs/docker/overlay/dd77d1edef54cdd4040b8f4c32afca86f7c3870f3b3b353063b406d2c3409220/merged/x/xx/xxx/xxxx': no such file or directory"
Nov 17 10:57:45 machine dockerd: time="2021-11-17T10:57:45.099051149Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.39/containers/b54433de86ec/archive returned error: permission denied"
```

possibly disk was corrupt or had a problem

or another example:

```
Nov 17 10:57:48 machine dbus[719]: [system] Activating service name='org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd' (using servicehelper)
Nov 17 10:57:48 machine dbus[719]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd'
Nov 17 10:57:49 machine setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/dockerd-ce from mounton access on the directory /logs/docker/overlay/dd77d1edef54cdd4040b8f4c32afca86f7c3870f3b3b353063b406d2c3409220/merged/host/net. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l efaad8a5-f04f-4783-9235-7048c915daa3
Nov 17 10:57:49 machine python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/dockerd-ce from mounton access on the directory /logs/docker/overlay/dd77d1edef54cdd4040b8f4c32afca86f7c3870f3b3b353063b406d2c3409220/merged/host/net.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that dockerd-ce should be allowed mounton access on the net directory by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'dockerd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-dockerd#012# semodule -i my-dockerd.pp#012
```

Selinux is preventing disk access for dockerd process.
So follow the suggested action:

```
root# ausearch -c 'dockerd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-dockerd
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i my-dockerd.pp

root# semodule -i my-dockerd.pp
```

Now the docker cp command worked on this system.